# No spacing after binary operator after math operator

Tags: macros, math-operators

There is some issue that I've come across while using `\mathop` where the space after a binary operator is not present when the first parameter is a operator.

##### Minimal Example

As you can see there is not the proper space after the binary operator `+`.

```
\begin{equation*}
    \mathop{x} + y
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

##### Particular Example

I've been using a macro for the differential operator after integrals. The error occurred during (approximately) the following usage:

```
\newcommand{\intop}[1]{\mathop{d#1}}
```

```
\begin{equation*}
    \int f(x) \intop{x} + y 
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: `\mathop{dx}` looks rather odd, usually people adjust the space before d not after x. you could use `{}+y` to compensate,

Comment: It may not necessarily be the case that your differential **op**erator requires the use of `\mathop`. Just set it as `dx`, or `\mathrm{d}x` (as in, `\newcommand{\intop}[1]{\mathrm{d}#1}`.

Comment: or `\newcommand{\intop}[1]{\mathop{}\!d#1}`

Answer (score 5):

TeX follows its own rules. With

```
\int f(x) \diff{x} + y
```

(note that you ***cannot*** define `\intop` that's already taken) you have

**Op Ord Open Ord Close Op Bin Ord**

but the combination **Op Bin** is invalid and therefore the **Bin** atom is transformed into **Ord**, with the consequence that TeX will insert a thin space between *x* and +, but no space between + and *y*.

Your idea of using `\mathop` in order to get a thin space between the function and the differential is good, but you shouldn't overdo.

After the *d* there will always be either an **Ord** or an **Open** atom and you just want a thin space before the *d*, not after it.

It would be wrong to define

```
\newcommand{\diff}[1]{\mathop{d}\!#1}
```

because the letter *d* would be moved down. It's much easier to use an empty `\mathop` and to adjust the spacing, because there would be a thin space between the (empty) `\mathop` and *d*:

```
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
```

without arguments. Then

```
\int f(x)\diff x+y
```

will have the correct spacing. You might do

```
\newcommand{\diff}[1]{\mathop{}\!d#1}
```

but I see no reason for preferring `\diff{x}` over `\diff x`.

***Caveat.*** Doing `\renewcommand{\intop}{...}` would be disastrous.

Comment: Looks like there is a missing "close" in your atom sequence example.

Comment: @mickep Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

### For the particular case only

If you want to write differentials, then one option is the package `derivative`. With the package you can simply write `\odif{x}` for an ordinary differential. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{derivative}
\begin{document}
\[\int f(x)\odif{x}+y\]
\end{document}
```